# Setting the JVM via the command line on Windows

Tags: java, windows, command-line, jvm

Is it possible to specify the JVM to use when you call "java jar jar_name.jar" . I have two JVM installed on my machine. I can not change JAVA_HOME as it may break code that is all ready running.

Kind Regards

Stephen

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes - just explicitly provide the path to java.exe. For instance:

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test>"c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.6.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.6.0_03-b05, mixed mode, sharing)

c:\Users\Jon\Test>"c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.6.0_12"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_12-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.2-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The easiest way to do this for a running command shell is something like:

```
set PATH=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin;%PATH%
```

For example, here's a complete session showing my default JVM, then the change to the path, then the new one:

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test>java -version
java version "1.6.0_12"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_12-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.2-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

c:\Users\Jon\Test>set PATH=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin;%PATH%

c:\Users\Jon\Test>java -version
java version "1.6.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.6.0_03-b05, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This won't change programs which explicitly use JAVA_HOME though.

Note that if you get the wrong directory in the path - including one that doesn't exist - you won't get any errors, it will effectively just be ignored.

Comment: Wow, this is a definitive skeeting. I was about to post roughly the first two lines of your answer when the notification popped up.

Comment: @Jon Skeet How can I do this in a Java program? I want to run a .jar using  a 32bit JRE, can I set the JRE path for the new process from Java code?

Comment: @Utku: Well when you create a process, you can pass the complete path to the executable...

Comment: @Jon Skeet Can you show me how to do it with an example please?

Comment: @Utku: Not in the context of a comment thread on an unrelated question, no. I suggest you do some research (search within Stack Overflow, for example) and ask a new question if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this via the command line arguments, assuming these are Sun VMs installed using the usual Windows InstallShield mechanisms with the JVM finder EXE in *system32*.

Type *java -help* for the options. In particular, see:

```
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-jre-restrict-search | -jre-no-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
```

Answer (score 0):

yes I often need to have 3 or more JVM's installed.  For example, I've noticed that sometimes the JRE is slightly different to the JDK version of the JRE.

My go to solution on Windows for a bit of 'packaging' is something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
@rem  _________________________
@rem
@set  JAVA_HOME=b:\lang\java\jdk\v1.6\u45\x64\jre
@rem
@set  JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
@set  VER=test
@set  WRK=%~d0%~p0%VER%
@rem
@pushd %WRK%
cd 
@echo.
@echo  %JAVA_EXE%  -jar %WRK%\openmrs-standalone.jar
       %JAVA_EXE%  -jar %WRK%\openmrs-standalone.jar 
@rem
@rem  _________________________
popd
endlocal
@exit /b
```

I think it is straightforward.  The main thing is the setlocal and endlocal give your app a "personal environment" for what ever it does -- even if there's other programs to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 installations of the JVM. 
Place the version upfront. 
Linux : export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:$PATH

This eliminates the ambiguity.