# How to test Java Desktop Application with diffrent Platform

Tags: java, testing, operating-system, desktop-application

I have develop on desktop application in java.
Now problem is that now i want test that application with different platform like 
**windows,Linux,MAC** with **64bit and 32bit** Os Comparability.
Another big issue is that i want to test maximum **Java JRE version like 1.5 to 1.7**.

How can i test my application?
Is there any tool available which help me solve this issue?

Comment: A virtual machine could help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have to setup environment for each and every test cases. If i use virtual machine that it will time consuming to test my application for each environments.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374193/possible-to-force-a-64-bit-jvm-to-use-32-bit-mode-via-the-argument-d32

Comment: @JavierV : Thank you for reply but do you means i have to check each and every platform. There are no such tools are available.

Comment: The problems you may face when developing for diferent environment usually are related to platform specific implementations. Thus, you really need to have the real architecture when testing. That's because when compiling Java, you obtain the same bytecode, but every SO has its own way of running that bytecode.
If you really need to do the testing, I would suggest you to use a pool of preconfigured virtual machines, start them and then run a set of tests on every machine. Suggestions: Check Selenium and java's Robot

Comment: in which framework did you used for desktop app? @subhashlamba

Comment: I have been used swing for develop java application

Answer (score 0):

To test on various operating systems, use a virtual machine like VirtualBox (free). Linux is free to get, but you will have to pay for other OSes. Mac doesn't like you installing it on anything but a Mac computer, so you might have to hack that, or buy a Mac. But you do have to set up a new environment every time. The testing wouldn't work otherwise, different operating systems are very different.

It's easier to test different JREs, check out the answers for this question: [Setting the JVM via the command line on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674903/setting-the-jvm-via-the-command-line-on-windows)