# Binding shaders - incorrect texturing of LWJGL objects

Tags: java, opengl, java-8, glsl, lwjgl

Note to future visitors: If you use the ftransform() method, you MUST bind the vertex data to attribute 0.

I am attempting to create a 3D terrain, which successfully looks like this:

[image]

However, when I switch to java 8, the game instead looks like this:

[image]

Long story short, the texturing is completely messed up, and I have absolutely no idea why. The terrain colour appears to be the same colour as the top left pixel of the texture.

I compile my shaders like this:

```
private static int loadShader(String file, int type){
    StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    int shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
    GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
    GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);
    if(GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS )== GL11.GL_FALSE){
        System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 500));
        System.err.println("Could not compile shader!");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return shaderID;
}
```

The shaders always successfully compile when using both java versions.

After attaching the shader, I then bind the shader attributes:

```
@Override
protected void bindAttributes() {
    int loc = 0;
    super.bindAttribute(GL20.glGetAttribLocation(loc, "position"), "position");
    super.bindAttribute(GL20.glGetAttribLocation(loc, "textureCoords"), "textureCoords");
    super.bindAttribute(GL20.glGetAttribLocation(loc, "normal"), "normal");
}

protected void bindAttribute(int attribute, String variableName){
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, attribute, variableName);
}
```

Although for some reason the "attribute" was always set to the same number, changing it does not appear to affect anything anywhere.

I'm then simply forwarding these coordinates onto the fragment shader:

```
#version 130

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = ftransform(); //I prefer the fixed-function pipeline. I may change some time. However, I don't believe it to be the cause of my issue.
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
    surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
    toLightVector = (vec3(500, 50000, 500)) - (transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz;
}

#version 130

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

uniform vec3 lightColour;

void main(void){
    vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
    vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);

    float nDot1 = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
    float brightness = max(nDot1, 0.2);
    brightness = brightness + 0.5;
    vec3 diffuse = brightness * vec3(1, 1, 1);
    vec4 text = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords);
    vec4 textureColor = vec4(diffuse, 1.0) * text;
    if(textureColor.a<0.01){
        discard;
    }
    out_Color = vec4(textureColor.r, textureColor.g, textureColor.b, textureColor.a);

}
```

I am clueless as to what the issue is. I do not have that much experience with the internals of GLSL and shaders yet, and I do not even know when the problem started to turn up, because I only noticed the issue after I started to send the game to others (I run on java 7).

I have tested the game using [Jon Skeet's method of changing versions of java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674903/setting-the-jvm-via-the-command-line-on-windows) and ran the exact same JAR files side by side, one with java 8 and one with java 7. Java 8 is definitely the deciding factor that is causing the issue.

Update:
This code -

```
System.out.println("Err1: " + GL11.glGetError());
    vertexShaderID = loadShader(vertexFile,GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShaderID = loadShader(fragmentFile,GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();
    System.out.println("Err2: " + GL11.glGetError());
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    System.out.println("Err3: " + GL11.glGetError());
    bindAttributes();
    System.out.println("Err4: " + GL11.glGetError());
    GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
    GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);
    System.out.println("Err5: " + GL11.glGetError());
    start();
    System.out.println("Err6: " + GL11.glGetError());
    System.out.println("Comiled shader!");
```

Prints out the following result:

```
Comiling shader!
Err1: 0
Error: 
Error: 
Err2: 0
Err3: 0
Err4: 1282 //This equals either GL_INVALID_VALUE or GL_INVALID_OPERATION
Err5: 0
Err6: 0
Comiled shader!
```

UPDATE:
In light of the first answer I received, I have modified my code to this:

```
@Override
protected void bindAttributes() {
    super.bindAttribute(1, "position");
    super.bindAttribute(2, "textureCoords");
    super.bindAttribute(3, "normal");
}
```

And now, this code does not print out any errors:

```
public ShaderProgram(String vertexFile,String fragmentFile){
    System.out.println("Comiling shader!");
    System.out.println("Err1: " + GL11.glGetError());
    vertexShaderID = loadShader(vertexFile,GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShaderID = loadShader(fragmentFile,GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();
    System.out.println("Err2: " + GL11.glGetError());
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    System.out.println("Err3: " + GL11.glGetError());
    bindAttributes();
    System.out.println("Err4: " + GL11.glGetError());
    GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
    GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);
    System.out.println("Err5: " + GL11.glGetError());
    start();
    System.out.println("Err6: " + GL11.glGetError());
    System.out.println("Comiled shader!");
}
Comiling shader!
Err1: 0
Error: 
Error: 
Err2: 0
Err3: 0
Err4: 0
Err5: 0
Err6: 0
Comiled shader!
Made StaticShader!
Made shaders!
```

Also, I am definitely binding the VAO data to the correct attributes:

```
public RawModel loadToVAO(float[] positions,float[] textureCoords,float[] normals,int[] indices, ArrayList<Vector3f> vertices){
    int vaoID = createVAO();
    bindIndicesBuffer(indices);
    storeDataInAttributeList(1 /*attribute*/,3,positions);
    storeDataInAttributeList(2/*attribute*/,2,textureCoords);
    storeDataInAttributeList(3/*attribute*/,3,normals);
    unbindVAO();
    return new RawModel(vaoID,indices.length, vertices);
}
```

However, it simply keeps crashing when the game starts to try and render anything. [Here's the crash report](http://pastebin.com/xxwBnWVY).

Here is my rendering code:

```
GL30.glBindVertexArray(downgrade.getVaoID());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        glTranslatef((float) x, 0f,(float) z);
        glScalef(1, 4, 1);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

For those wondering, I am missing attribute "0" because attribute 0 is for the fixed-function pipeline, and it throws a GL_INVALID_VALUE if I bind that attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that the `bindAttributes()` function would work reliably in any Java version. Maybe you were just fortunate that the attribute locations ended up being what you expected them to be.

Looking at this code:

```
protected void bindAttributes() {
    int loc = 0;
    super.bindAttribute(GL20.glGetAttribLocation(loc, "position"), "position");
    super.bindAttribute(GL20.glGetAttribLocation(loc, "textureCoords"), "textureCoords");
    super.bindAttribute(GL20.glGetAttribLocation(loc, "normal"), "normal");
}

protected void bindAttribute(int attribute, String variableName){
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, attribute, variableName);
}
```

You're calling `glGetAttribLocation()` with `0` as the first argument. The first argument needs to be the id of a shader program. So these calls will result in an error.

Taking a step back, I think you misunderstood what these calls do:

1. `glBindAttribLocation()` can be used to **set** the attribute locations **before** the shader program is linked.
2. `glGetAttribLocation()` can be used to **get** the (automatically assigned) attribute locations **after** the shader program was linked.

You normally use one of these two, not both. If you want to specify the locations, use the first approach. If you want to let the shader compiler/linker assign locations, and get the resulting locations, you use the second approach.

Since you call `bindAttributes()` before `glLinkProgram()`, it looks like you're going for approach 1. So you should only be calling `glBindAttribLocation()`. Say if you wanted to assign location values sequentially, you could use something like:

```
int loc = 0;
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, loc++, "position");
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, loc++, "textureCoords");
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, loc++, "normal");
```

The actual locations you specify have to match what you're using elsewhere in your code, particularly as the first arguments to `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` and `glVertexAttribPointer()`.

Comment: I thought that fTransform() took up attribute location 0. Am I incorrect about that?

Comment: I've added my new code in the question. However, the game is now just crashing upon the `glDrawArrays()` call.

Comment: @Joehot200 You're mixing various ways of using OpenGL. For example, fixed function attributes and generic attributes. Using the matrix stack and building your own transformations. You'll need to decide if you want to stick with legacy functionality, or use only features in the core profile. You can't just mix these things arbitrarily. But this really goes far beyond the scope of the original question.