# Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*') Error

Tags: java

**ISSUE**:  I am building cordova app, which show error in environmental variables. but it was set correctly.

**Error** :

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 14.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

How can i overcome this error

Comment: Please go through this link  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask    to understand how to ask questions in this forum.

Comment: Please Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Doesn't the log you've posted seem quite obvious? have you read it carefully?

Comment: the log say that you have jdk 14.0.2 installed on you machine, but you need the jdk version 1.8.* to work.  for me i have java 11, but using IntelIJ , i just specify the version of java that i want to use, and some times i use java 8 (1.8.x).

Comment: you can install java 8 (1.8.x) on your machine besid java 14. and then use it.  you can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674903/setting-the-jvm-via-the-command-line-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

The log say that you have java 14 (jdk 14.0.2) installed on you machine, but you need java 8 (jdk version 1.8.*) for your program to work.

You can install [java 8](https://www.java.com/fr/download/) (1.8.x) on your machine besid java 14. And then use it. you can check this :[Setting the JVM via the command line on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674903/setting-the-jvm-via-the-command-line-on-windows)

For me, i have java 11 on my machine. Some times, i need java, using IntellIJ , I just specify the version of java that i want to use, on modul setting, language level.

Good Luck.